# ColdFusion error retrieving accept-language from GetHttpRequestData().headers

Tags: coldfusion, header, http-accept-language

I'm attempting to pull the variable `GetHttpRequestData().headers.accept-language` in ColdFusion 2018, but am getting an error.

1. The main object `GetHttpRequestData().headers` looks fine. This is information from the html request header.
2. I can also pull back other values in the headers object like `GetHttpRequestData().headers.host` or  `GetHttpRequestData().headers.accept`
3. However, if the variable name contains a dash ie. `GetHttpRequestData().headers.accept-language`, I get an error because CF Thinks I'm executing a mathematical function.

How can I return this variable? It should be simple.

[cffiddle example](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=7c018098-5ae5-45e9-8f63-eba02aa01609/dd9eb73f-74b2-4aee-867f-76437b6e8588/a8ec495a-80d6-4c2e-b194-ac91c9757830.cfm)

```
// Dump the Object    
writeDump(var="#GetHttpRequestData().headers#",format="html")

// Dump a result in the Object OK
writeDump(var="#GetHttpRequestData().headers.host#",format="text")

// Dump a result in the Object OK
writeDump(var="#GetHttpRequestData().headers.accept#",format="text")

// CF Thinks I'm executing a mathematical function
// when structure variable has a dash in the name
try {
    writeDump(var="#GetHttpRequestData().headers.accept-language#",format="text")
} catch (any e) {
    writeOutput("Error: " & e.message);
}
```

Comment: Are the `cgi` variables of any use?

Answer (score 3):

Answer to ColdFusion variables with dash separators.

Use the chained variable in the following manner:

```
 #GetHttpRequestData().headers['accept-language']#
```

- note the drop of the point separator

Comment: Yep. FYI, when using dot-notation you're limited to keys that conform to CF's [variable naming rules](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/creating-variables.html) (i.e. must start with a letter/underscore, can't contain spaces or other invalid characters like a dash, etc...).  Whenever dealing with exotic or invalid variable names, use structure (or associative array) notation instead.